# How to patch-package --include multiple files of the same package

Tags: yarnpkg, patch, patch-package

Is it possible to patch-package --include multiple files? I have two files under the same package but they're in different paths. What would be the best way to include only the changes from these 2 files?

```
yarn patch-package <package-name> --include <file1> <file2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `patch-package` docs, you can pass a regex to the `--include` flag. So, including two files can be achieved as follows:

```
yarn patch-package <package-name> --include (<file1>|<file2>)
```